# Set page height snappy PDF

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, snappy

i want a specic height of my pdf but i get the error of `Call to undefined method niklasravnsborg\LaravelPdf\PdfWrapper::setOption()` can someone help me about this?

here's my approach.

```
         $format["title"] = "A4";
        $format["format"] = "A4";
        $format["default_font"] = "sans-serif";

        $pdf = PDF2::setOption('page-height', '139.7')->loadView('member.payroll.payroll_payslipv1', $data, [], $format);
        return $pdf->stream('document.pdf');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
$pdf = SnappyPdf::loadView('member.payroll.payroll_payslipv1', $data, [], $format)
->setOption('page-height', '139.7');
```